# Is there a word to describe when things are moving individually, but have a net velocity of zero?

Tags: kinematics, terminology, velocity, inertial-frames

I know this is a strange question, but I know there must be a word for it.

So imagine a case where, taken as a whole, the net velocity of all particles equals zero, but each individual particle is moving. Here is what I am picturing:

[image: Text]

For root words, I tried quasistatic, but it doesn't seem to have the same meaning since it is emphasizing the stability rather than the movement. I have thought of metastatic, using **meta-* meaning change and **sta-* which has the same root in stasis, but that one has the unfortunate connotation of cancer. As you can see, I am not at all well versed in linguistics or etymology, so help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What does “the net velocity of all particles equals zero” mean in plain words?

Comment: It means they're bounded, basically. The situation wouldn't continue otherwise.

Comment: In plain words, zero-sum is good. Also, you can think about a case of two particles: if they have equal and opposite velocities-- lets say v and -v-- the sum would be v_t = v - v = 0. You can expand that case to many particles. @JohnLawler Yeah thinking about it off the cuff I do believe they would have to be bounded, lets say by a potential wall or molecular bonds, or else they would disperse.

Comment: The question as posed seems misguided (or perhaps mistated?). The things that you say are moving are *not* the things that have a net velocity of zero. It is their combination that has zero velocity. This is no different than talking about the combined height of all Americans - which is not the height of any particular American.

Comment: This is confusing. I thought *velocity* was a **vector**, and that only *speed* was a **scalar**.

Comment: For a large collection of particles (i.e., molecules), it's called temperature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be described as *pedesis* or as *random motion*.

The picture shows the velocities of many particles (as in a gas the molecules all move around). *Velocity* is a vector: it has a *speed* and it has *direction*. In 3 dimensions this means that it has three components mutually at right angles: for present convenience, call them up/down, left/right, towards/away.

The *net velocity* in this case is the *average velocity* of all particles. To say it is zero is to say that the averages of each component of the vectors is zero. There is as much motion left as right, up as down, towards as away.

> *vector* = a representation of something that has both *direction* and *size*
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vector)

Note that the average *velocity* is zero although the average *speed* is not. The particles are all bouncing around in the box with various speeds but as a group they are going nowhere, so the average velocity is zero.

The group of particles is showing "random motion".

*Brownian motion*, or *pedesis* (from Ancient Greek: πήδησις /pɛ̌ːdɛːsis/ "leaping"), is the *random motion* of particles suspended in a medium (a liquid or a gas).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion)

Comment: The question confused me because of the vector/scalar squishiness of velocity vs speed.